# Preventing 404 Page Not Found: Faviconico/index in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, favicon

I have a CodeIgniter 3 application with `log_threshold` of 1. Most of the logs I get are `404 Page Not Found: Faviconico/index`. I want to receive 404s in my logs, but not this one as it's not particularly useful or informative. I've created the following routes.

```
$route['Faviconico'] = 'general/empty_response';
$route['Faviconico/index'] = 'general/empty_response';
```

This is the general controller method `empty_response`.

```
// Serves nothing
public function empty_response()
{
    return false;
}
```

Visiting `http://example.com/Faviconico/index` directly in the browser no longer cause the log where as it use to, but somehow users are still causing this log to happen.

**How can I prevent logging of `404 Page Not Found: Faviconico/index`?**

Comment: Odd, it should be `/favicon.ico`, unless you have some other routing going on. Try adding a favicon.ico to your root directory.

Comment: @aynber That route is causing `Faviconico/index` log errors! Post this as an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers look for a [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) to show next to the address bar. Add a favicon.ico to your root directory and that error should disappear.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, I have my favicon in a folder, works in all supported browsers, and to keep the favicon only there I just added a route to catch this. `$route['favicon.ico'] = 'general/empty_response';`